# how to initialize style in i html element in kotlin/js?

Tags: html, css, kotlin, kotlin-js

```
val Welcome = FC<WelcomeProps> { props ->
var name by useState(props.name)

div {


    css {
        width = 100.pct
        height = 500.px
        margin = 0.px
        padding = 0.px
        position = absolute
        display = Display.block
    }

    button {

        css {
            position = absolute
            top = 50.pct
            backgroundColor = NamedColor.transparent
            width = Auto.auto
            borderColor = NamedColor.transparent
            right = 0.px
        }

        i {
            className = ClassName("fas fa-chevron-right fa-xs")
        }

        for (i in 0 until 1) {

            img {
                css {
                    width = 100.pct
                    height = 100.pct
                    margin = 0.px
                    padding = 0.px
                }
                src =
                    "https://www.pixelstalk.net/wp-content/uploads/2016/06/Volleyball-Wallpapers-HD-For-Desktop.jpg"
            }
        }

        button {

            css {
                position = absolute
                top = 50.pct
                backgroundColor = NamedColor.transparent
                width = Auto.auto
                borderColor = NamedColor.transparent
                left = 0.px
            }

            **i {
                className = ClassName("fas fa-chevron-left fa-xs")
                style = ??????????
            }**
        }
    }
}
```

}

Hello guys This is my first practice with kotlin/js I want to design a webApplication with kotlin/js my problem is that I have one class in i elemnt for awesome font and i cant use css element like other places so I decided to use style element but I don't know how to initilize it
sorry for my bad english

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you're importing the correct i from this librabry `import react.dom.html.ReactHTML.i`.